# How can I improve my IELTS writing skills?

Tags: english, writing, exams

I have problems with sentence connectors, structure and vocabulary. I need to get IELTS test band 7.
Please provide some learning material.

I tried to find something on google, but there are many websites, which confuse me and I couldn't find a proper and constructed article about it.

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE. Can you tell a little about your background knowledge and what you have problems with, in particular?

Comment: Hey Tommi, Thank you for your answer. So, in particular, I have problems with sentence connectors, structure and vocabulary. I need to get IELTS test band 7.

Comment: I edited the extra detail to be a part of the question. Hopefully someone can answer it.

Comment: Are you looking for materials that help your prepare specifically for IELTS? Or is it OK to suggest resources that are independent of IELTS? In that case, I would post either the vocabulary question or the grammar question separately from this one, since they require different types of resources and approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should understand if you're taking General or Academic IELTS. For Academic IELTS, you should [describe a graph](https://ieltsprofi.com/blog/ielts-writing-task-1/) and [write an essay](https://ieltsprofi.com/blog/ielts-writing-task-2/) while for General IELTS you have to [write a letter](https://ieltsprofi.com/blog/ielts-general-writing-task-1/) and [essay](https://ieltsprofi.com/blog/ielts-writing-task-2/).

All in all, you should make sure to structure your writing assignments properly and aim at a high band.

For sentence structure, as mentioned in the above answer, Grammarly could be helpful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Are you in any way affiliated with the site you are referencing (IELTS Profi)? If yes, please mention this explicitly in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're looking for something like an *app*, *web platform*, or *course* that teaches you writing, but a more effective solution might be to **download Grammarly**.

Grammarly is an excellent tool (don't worry, I'm not sponsored) that corrects your writing (both grammar and spelling), and it's much better/smarter than the built-in grammar checker in MS Word or Google Docs.

Let me know if that helps!

[www.grammarly.com](http://www.grammarly.com)

Comment: I agree, Grammarly and other writing aids are fantastic because they give suggestions and help you understand why some ways of writing may be better than others. It is all about thinking and trying out different ways of writing so you can become more familiar and relaxed with connectors and the pros and cons of different structures etc